# Mongo Partial Filter Expression

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use create a unique index with a partial filter expression.  I've tried all sorts of different things, but I keep getting syntax errors in Compass.   Any suggestions on how this should be written. I've tried things like:

```
{partialFilterExpression: aim_id: {$type: "string"}}
aim_id: {$type: "string"}
aim_id": {$type: "string"}
```

[image]

Comment: `{partialFilterExpression: aim_id: {$type: "string"}}` is not a valid command, if is even not a valid JSON. Maybe have a quick look at [Partial Indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-partial/)

Comment: I was desperate.  I tried quotes, no quotes.  this and that....  yep, definitely looked at the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just "played" with MongoDB Compass (v1.34.2), and it seems an acceptable incantation for your `partialFilterExpression` is:

```json
{"aim_id": {"$type": "string"}}
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I tried it, but it then gives me a "You must select a field name and type".  which I do, right at the top "aim_id", and "1 (asc)"

Comment: actually, that did it!  There seems to be a bug with Compass where I have to fill out the partial expression box first, then select the field/direction thing at the top for it to work...

Comment: @keynesiancross  I tried lots of combinations for the `partialFilterExpression`, but I didn't try different orders of assigning the index field and the `partialFilterExpression`.  I assigned the index field first and then the `partialFilterExpression`.  Compass is still a work-in-progress - I'm confident it will continue to improve.

Comment: I really appreciate the help! I never would have figured it out.